# Please help this Subquery returned more than 1 value. error

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

My query is

```
SELECT ACCOUNTNUM,
       NAME,
       ADDRESS,
       PHONE,
       TELEFAX,
       INVOICEACCOUNT,
       CUSTGROUP,
       PAYMTERMID,
       CURRENCY,
       DIMENSION,
       CELLULARPHONE,
       STATISTICSGROUP,
       PAYMMODE,
       NAMEALIAS,
       CONTACTPERSONID,
       STREET,
       PARTYID,
       SEGMENTID,
       TAXGROUP,
       DATAAREAID,
       ISNULL (
                 (SELECT PERCENT1 AS DiscCount
                  FROM PRICEDISCTABLE
                  WHERE (DATAAREAID = CUSTTABLE.DATAAREAID)
                    AND (ACCOUNTRELATION = CUSTTABLE.ACCOUNTNUM)), 0) / 100 AS DiscCount,

  (SELECT NAME
   FROM CONTACTPERSON
   WHERE (DATAAREAID = CUSTTABLE.DATAAREAID)
     AND (CUSTACCOUNT = CUSTTABLE.ACCOUNTNUM)
     AND (CONTACTPERSONID = CUSTTABLE.CONTACTPERSONID)) AS ContactName,

  (SELECT PHONE
   FROM CONTACTPERSON AS CONTACTPERSON_1
   WHERE (DATAAREAID = CUSTTABLE.DATAAREAID)
     AND (CUSTACCOUNT = CUSTTABLE.ACCOUNTNUM)
     AND (CONTACTPERSONID = CUSTTABLE.CONTACTPERSONID)) AS ContactPhone,
              ISNULL (
                        (SELECT STATGROUPNAME
                         FROM CUSTSTATISTICSGROUP
                         WHERE (DATAAREAID = CUSTTABLE.DATAAREAID)
                           AND (CUSTSTATISTICSGROUP = CUSTTABLE.STATISTICSGROUP)), 0) AS StatisticsName
FROM CUSTTABLE
WHERE (CUSTGROUP = N'DOM')
  AND (DATAAREAID = N'OTN')
  AND (STATISTICSGROUP = N'S010');
```

I obtain the error "Subquery returned more than 1 value....".

Help me please.

Comment: Use `SELECT TOP 1 ACCOUNTNUM ...`

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to one of your subqueries returning more than one row for the **ISNULL** function. The **ISNULL** function is meant to deal with one value - not a set of values (like **Max**).

Run each of your subqueries to check out the data and change it to get only one value returned. Use **DISTINCT** if you get multiple records with the same value, **Top 1** if you just want one random value from a set, or **MAX** if your looking to get the maximum (or MIN) of the set - depending on your needs. You may find that you may need to add more criteria to your subquery.

```
SELECT PERCENT1 AS DiscCount
                  FROM PRICEDISCTABLE
                  WHERE (DATAAREAID = CUSTTABLE.DATAAREAID)
                    AND (ACCOUNTRELATION = CUSTTABLE.ACCOUNTNUM)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325(v=sql.105).aspx